DLL is not loading when I try to run my application
I want to use a function that is on a DLL I made on C# and I want to use it on a Python Script but the problem is not my Python script, the problem is that it seems that the System.Drawing.Common namespace of C# is not loaded in the DLL.
So the problem I got is this one:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
File name: 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
at POSprintComandsDLL.Class_Print_Comands.Imprimir_Comprobante_Perdido()
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)*

I configured my C# script to only work on Windows 10.0 and upper and also I'm using the NuGet System.Drawing.Common package in the project. It didn't work.

how do you reference C# dll file , is System.Drawing.Common in the same directory ?

No, I imported System.Drawing.Common into my csproj with the NuGet package manager

do you see a dll with such name in your build output? Do you use framework or .net core/.net6? If you "publish" dotnet publish or in framework set <OutDir> in project file, do you see this DLL then?
If you see this DLL after performing as explained above ^^ and still getting this error, then you need to add Dependency redirect. You might have 2 components that use 2 different versions of the same dll

that is the issue all depending dll's have to be together. when u publish your csproj file all outout should be put together with your csproj dll.

I'm using .NET 8.0 on my project

Then run dotnet publish yourproj.csproj ..... and see if this file is in the output folder. you can use ILDASM to check what Assembly version of this file it this file is in the output folder

T.S THANKS, it worked, just copy all the files that the command created and paste them in the folder I'm working with, but I have a question... Do I need all the files or just my DLL and the anothers DLLs that my DLL needs?

@JoseAndresMoraila there are 2 modes of publishing. --no-self-contained true/false
If you do self contained - it will add ALL dlls - your and the framework. This can run on the machine where you don't have .net runtime installed. If you do non-self contained - this will only have your DLLs but will only run on the machine with runtime pre-installed  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish

I'm developing a software that I want to run on my brother's PC and another PCs because they don't have .NET and I don't think they want to have it on their PCs, so I will use dotnet publish --self-contained true

many PCs/Win come with some version of .net already installed because windows components use it
